# how to get the most purchased item - java

Tags: java

I have an item:

```
String name;
int amountPurchased;
Date date;
```

I have a list of items, some of which share the same name, and some which share the same name and date. What I want to do is sum the `amountPurchased` of items that have the same `name` and `date`.

I want to be able to get the most purchased today, yesterday, this week and this month.

I tried to group it by those items having the same date `dd/MM/yyyy` and then get the most purchased item of the list by date.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through your list and make a new list for different items (checking the name). After that, you will have a couple of lists containing the same items - you can choose the most purchased item by checking the Count() of those lists.
Next thing, you can diverse that list by day, month or year and count items bought in that specific date, giving you the expected result.

It would be a lot easier if that would be done in the Database - one query would give you all of the answers

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8, you can do this with Streams:

```java
import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
```

```java
// List<Item> items = ...

Map<Date, List<Item>> mostPurchasedItemsPerDay = items.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Item::getDate,
                collectingAndThen(
                        groupingBy(Item::getName),
                        itemsPerName -> itemsPerName.values().stream()
                                .max(comparingInt(itemsOfSameName -> itemsOfSameName.stream()
                                        .mapToInt(Item::getAmountPurchased)
                                        .sum()))
                                .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
                )));
```

What it does is

- it takes your list of items and groups it by Date
  (it doesn't allow null, and I assume all dates represent "start of day")
- for each such date

  - it groups the items per name
  - and then finds the name for which the sum of `amountPurchased` is largest
    .
    `max` will return an `Optional` that you need to unpack that using `.get()`.
    Sometimes the compiler issues a warning for that because it doesn't know that the Optional is never empty in this case. To avoid that you can use `.orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)` instead.

---

**edit:**
If you want entire groups of dates (e.g., "last week", "last month") you should replace `Item::getDate` with a function that maps an item to the corresponding date group.